# CSS top different with same percentage in the same browser

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-7

I'm currently building a Drupal website and I seem to have stumbled across something weird.

When logged-in to the site, percentage positions are calculated differently vs. when not logged-in. I've double, triple checked and there are no extra style sheets affecting the concerned elements that are supplied when logged in. Viewed in Firefox (two instances for side-by-side) this is how it turns out:

[image: When logged in]

This is when logged in: top: 50%; calculated as 136.067px

[image: Anonymous User]

This is as seen by an anonymous user: top: 50%; calculated as 900.4px

I really can't figure it out, as there is no difference and as seen these are both calculated from the same rule, using the same selectors on the same line of the same CSS file.

(Yes, I know Firefox and Firefox DE are separate browsers, but I do get the same results using the exact same copy - this was for convenience of screenshotting. This also happens in Chrome and Opera, haven't tried IE yet.)

JSFiddle:
This is basically what happens when not logged in, but it doesn't seem to be such an extreme effect.

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle?

Comment: Has the element a parent with position relative?

Comment: Could the admin navbar be affecting your numbers?

Comment: That would be the admin navbar making it look correct... the position when logged in is where it should be.

Comment: So who do you want it to look right for, the users or just you as admin?

Comment: All users. Anonymous and admin.

Comment: Without code we're probably not going to be able to help but it sounds as though the navbar need to be taken out of the flow. Positioning will usually allow that. But it sounds like a lot of work just to make an admin happy..

Comment: @Paulie_D When logged in, it looks right. When not, it doesn't. It's when logged out that I need to fix..

Comment: That's what I'm saying, you should design it for **everyone** who is logged out. It doesn't matter what it looks like for admins...they *know* it's going to look different. Other than that I'm sure there are plug-ins to make the admin bar positionable.